# How to package already defined classes and export it in dll?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, dll

This is the first time I deal with dll. I am using Opencv3 and Visual C++ to write a face recognition program. I have to load the CascadeClassigier, FaceRecognizer and VideoCapture into the memory before recognizing. They are all classes defined in opencv. And I want to package these classes into a new class and export that with a DLL. The intention I am doing so is to avoid include that many opencv files in my application program.
Here is my code (file name is RecFuncs.h):

```
#pragma once
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/face/facerec.hpp"
#include "opencv2/face/predict_collector.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#ifdef FACEDLL_EXPORTS
#define FACEDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FACEDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace FaceFuncs {
    class FACEDLL_API Load
    {
    public:
        Ptr<face::FaceRecognizer> a;
        CascadeClassifier b;
        VideoCapture c;
    };
}
```

And when I import my dll class, It seems that the class is not complete or undefined. How can I achieve my intention? Any idea or?

Comment: I don't see the point in avoiding "so many opencv" files. If you wanted, link statically for the end product but anyways CMake will handle dependencies be it many or not. That said, the header doesn't reveal your cause.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Error:Incomplete type is not allowed

Comment: One of those headers must be forward declaring a type. You might have to add a level of indirection so the dll h file doesnt have to include all of those library header files.